# Scanning for BLE devices with Android 13 (permission requests)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions

I would like to scan for BLE devices with my Android app. The problem is that Android won't give me the bluetoothLeScanner instance (it is always null). Also no permission requests pop up at all (which might be the cause for the problem).

Here's the code I came up with:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Button press starts the scan
        val fab: View = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view -> bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(bleScanner) }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Get required permissions
        getPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
        getPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
        getPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
        getPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    }

    private fun getPermission(perm: String) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                perm
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(perm), 2)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(bleScanner)
        super.onStop()
    }

    private val bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner
        get() {
            val bluetoothManager =
                applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
            val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
            return bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
        }

    private val bleScanner = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            Log.d(
                "DeviceListActivity",
                "onScanResult: ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}"
            )
        }

        override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results)
            Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onBatchScanResults:${results.toString()}")
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onScanFailed: $errorCode")
        }
        
    }
}
```

I also added these lines to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Why does no permission request pop up?
Could the missing permissions be the cause of the null-ed BLE instance?

Comment: Just to confirm, is `bluetoothAdapter` non-null but `bluetoothLeScanner` null? What device are you testing on, and does it have the necessary hardware?